# How to upload large .RRF files into MySQL / phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

Trying to import some .RRF files into MySQL but the phpMyAdmin has a 50MB limit and doesn't seem to support direct .RRF file imports.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by downloading MySQL Workbench and then running a script that imports the .RRF files into MySQL remotely.